# Spooler that automatically switches to the active printer?

Tags: printer, automation, print-spooler, zebra-printer

We have a Zebra ethernet thermal printer on the production floor. SAP ERP prints batches of labels on this printer. But sometimes, labels are lost, due to printer problems.

Now, we want to add another thermal printer and have a "smart" spooler that will prints on the available printer, depending of the printer's status read from the IO's of the printer (low media, low ribbon, online/offline, paused, etc). So SAP would still send it's labels "blindly" to the spooler and it would print the labels to then active printer. The printers IO's would be connected to a small Siemens PLC.

Is it possible to do something like this? How can we do that? Any idea??

thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Can be done on Windows if both printers are absolutely identical.

Comment: The zebra Windows driver is "smart" enough to knows which printer is available based on its status???

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the option *Printer Pool*, which is a group of identical printers with
the same driver.
A Printer Pool appears as a single printer on your system, where Windows takes care
of directing the output to the actual printers in the pool.

To create the pool:

- In Devices and Printers, right-click on the first printer to be included and
  choose *Printing preferences*
- In the *Ports* tabs, check *Enable Printer Pooling*
- In the list of ports, select all the ports you want included in the printer pool
- Click OK.

Comment: this method is probably fine with desktop printers, but what about thermal printers who gives outputs on low ribbon/low media signals. We want to redirect the printing to the printer who don't have any warning.

Comment: What do you mean by warning? And why wouldn't it work for thermal printers?

Comment: a low ribbon or low media are warnings. The signal can be send to a PLC to warn an operator to change the ribbon roll, for example. Those signals are hardware.